# Vector calculus simplification in calculation of generalized force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, differentiation, vector-fields

Consider a system of $N$ particles subject to forces $\vec F_i\ (i=1\dots N)$ that derive from a potential $V$. My lecture notes propose a simple proof that

$$Q_j = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}$$

where the generalized forces are defined as $Q_j = \sum_i \vec F_i\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_i}{\partial q_j}$. It goes like this:

$$
Q_j = \sum_i \vec F_i\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_i}{\partial q_j}
    = -\sum_i\vec\nabla_i V\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_i}{\partial q_j} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}
$$

I'm trying to understand the last step in detail, but I get a wrong answer by a factor $N$. For example with two particles, and writing $\vec r_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$, I have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_i\vec\nabla_i V\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_i}{\partial q_j}
&= \vec\nabla_1V\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_1}{\partial q_j} + 
  \vec\nabla_2V\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_2}{\partial q_j} \\
&= (\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial x_1},
   \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial y_1},
   \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial z_1})
\cdot(\tfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial q_j},
      \tfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial q_j},
      \tfrac{\partial z_1}{\partial q_j})
+ (\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial x_2},
   \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial y_2},
   \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial z_2})
\cdot(\tfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial q_j},
      \tfrac{\partial y_2}{\partial q_j},
      \tfrac{\partial z_2}{\partial q_j}) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j} \\[1ex]
&= 2\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_j}
\end{aligned}
$$
What did I do wrong to get this factor 2?

Comment: There's already a question on the same result (or very close) but a with a different proof: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271213/ . But I'm really trying to understand this proof.

Comment: This is just the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) of calculus applied to a function of more than one variable. There is no factor 6.

Comment: Thanks, that corrects a factor 3 (I edited the question accordingly). But I'm still wrong by a factor $N$ (factor 2 in the example).

Comment: (As Pedro Fernando made clear, I was confused about the $V$ function, it's "just the chain rule" as you say :-). )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are making incorrect use of the chain rule for derivatives. In the last step

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_{j}}=\sum_{i}\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial x_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{1}}\frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial q_{j}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y_{1}}\frac{\partial y_{1}}{\partial q_{j}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z_{1}}\frac{\partial z_{1}}{\partial q_{j}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial q_{j}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y_{1}}\frac{\partial y_{2}}{\partial q_{j}}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z_{2}}\frac{\partial z_{2}}{\partial q_{j}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think clearly about $V$ being a 6-variable function.